# Displaying a hidden div not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using below javascript to add \ remove some hidden `div` depends upon user selection.I see the code works fine in chrome and in firefox. But in IE  eventhough hidden divs are displaying, it keeps in disabled state.what is the problem here

[**PHP FIDDLE SETUP**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d2g-euj)

```
function AddNewFa() 
{
var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
    if( facount < 10)
{
        facount = facount+1;
            for(i=3;i<10;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                    {
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                        $('#fa-select-'+i).removeAttr("disabled");
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast");
                        $('#fa-select-'+i).attr("disabled","disabled");

                        }

                }
    $('#countfa').val(facount);  
}
CheckButtons()
} 


function RemoveNewFa() 
{
var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),10) ;
    if( facount >3)
{
        facount = facount-1;
            for(i=3;i<10;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                    {
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                        $('#fa-select-'+i).removeAttr("disabled");
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast");
                        $('#fa-select-'+i).attr("disabled","disabled");

}                       
                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount); 
            }   
CheckButtons()          
    }   

function CheckButtons() {
    var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
    if( facount >=9 )
    { $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
    if( facount >=4 )
    { $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}
    if( facount <=3 )
    { $('#removefa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
    if( facount <=8 )
    { $('#addfa').removeAttr("disabled");} 
}

$(document).ready(function() {CheckButtons();});
```

Comment: try show() and hide() method of jquery.

Comment: I don't know that it will solve your problem, but in a general sense to set the disabled state it's better to use `.prop("disabled", true)` (or `false`).